# GNU Grub showing at boot

Tags: boot, grub2, gnu

After I reinstalled Lubuntu and downloaded the updates, I restarted it. When I powered on the system, the GNU Grub 2.02 menu shows it has choices like Ubuntu, More options, Memtest, etc.

Comment: no, it has choices like: Ubuntu, More options,Memtest, etc.

Comment: And your question is *why doesn't it boot from the Grub boot menu*?